# Does spark cache rdds automatically?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm submitting a spark job (spark-submit).

**Problem**

I'm loading an rdd by reading avro files from HDFS.
Then I filter the rdd & count it (job-1).
Then I filter it again using a different criteria and count it (job-2).

- In the logs I see that the FileInputFormat is reading 60 files the first time.  But it doesn't read any files the second time.
- Also when I do `rdd.toDebugString` I do not see the parent rdd being cached.

**Details**

Here is the code:

```
JavaRdd<Record> records = loadAllRecords();
JavaRDD<Record> type1Recs = records.filter(selectType1());
JavaRDD<Record> type2Recs = records.filter(selectType2());
log.info(type1Recs.count());
log.info(type2Recs.count());
```

When I look at the rdd debug info for the first count:

```
  .....
  .....
  |   MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at xxxx.java:61 []
  |   NewHadoopRDD[0] at newAPIHadoopRDD at xxxxx.java:64 []
```

When I look at the rdd debug info for the second count:

```
  .....
  .....
  |   MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at EventRepo.java:61 []
  |   NewHadoopRDD[0] at newAPIHadoopRDD at xxxxx.java:64 []
```

If I were catching NewHadoopRDD would have some catching info associated to it in the debug string...

However, I do realize that in both instances the RDD is referred to as `NewHadoopRDD[0]`.  **What is the `[0]` mean in this context is that the id?**  I think of RDD has a handle so I'm not sure the what the significance of the reusing the same handle would be?

When I do the first `count` I see in the logs:

```
FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 60
```

But I do not see a similar log for the second count.  Shouldn't the `records` Rdd be loaded all over again?

Finally the second count is faster than the first which leads me to believe the data is in memory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this line, `FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 60`, it belongs to RDD's metadata. This one outputs in `NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions`. It's lazy but only runs once. You can say that RDD's metadata is cached. But the data of this RDD (the data in the files) is not cached.

Comment: Ah interesting! so in fact it is reading the data all over again?

Answer (score 4):

> Does spark cache rdds automatically?

Sometimes, yes. The RDDs are cached automatically in cases of a shuffle.

You might have observed "skipped stages" in the spark Web UI, for example.

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations

In the other cases, you will need to call `rdd.cache` or its variants.

Comment: I'm starting to see these "skipped stages" and they're happening before I do a full outer join...so in fact it is doing caching automatically...but I didn't see this in the documentation you had linked in your answer...